# Does md5 stop SQL Injection

Tags: php, md5, sql-injection

Ok,

So, i'm a little unsure on this.

I have a url parameter **username**.

and I have this statement

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_hash = md5($_GET['username'])
```

Is this secure?

Upon account creation an md5 hashed version of the username and the password are stored.

I'm confused as this seems so simple, if md5 stops sql injection why isn't username and password always saved in hash form?

Comment: You really shouldn't use [MD5 password hashes](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure) and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: To solve SQL-injection this way, you would have to encode EVERYTHING in the database.

Comment: and I would retrieve the data, not its hash.

Comment: Here's something that tells you [what sql injection is](http://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/sql-injection/)

Comment: MD5 is a highly insecure due to the fact that it is not only fast but that there are numerous hash collisions as well as numerous rainbow tables available for this function. It is now simply a stumbling block for an attacker, rather than a sealed door. http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure

Comment: I think the poster is implying to work that both the `username` and the `password` are hashed and then submitted to the database for checking, such that no unencrypted data is ever even touched before a login is validated. May be a secure idea but MD5 is not the hash to use for it.

Comment: In your example code, are you calling `md5()` in PHP or in SQL?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this will avoid SQL injection, because `md5()` always returns a string of hex code.

But it isn't a general solution to SQL-injection. You would have to encode almost all the data in your tables in MD5 format. For instance,

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET fullname = '" . md5($_GET['fullname']) . "'
        WHERE id = '" . md5($_GET['id']) . "'";
```

But MD5 is a one-way hash, so there would be no way of displaying the full name that was stored this way.

Comment: @Gumbo Fixed, added quotes around the MD5 ID.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is no, MD5 does not prevent SQL injection.  Proper coding is the best way to handle this.

Reason being in this case is that your query string parameter is allowing direct access to the sql.  E.g. what if the user sends you:

```
?username=%27a%27);DROP%20TABLE%20users;%20--
```

That fakes the MD5 function out and drops the users table.  Of course they have to know somethings about your database in order to do this.  The correct way to handle it would be to MD5 the value before it went into the SQL.  In PHP it would be something like this:

```
$username = $GET['username'];
$hashed_username = md5($username);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_hash = '$hashed_username'"
```

Or the best solution would be to use bound variables in queries where you let the SQL libraries handle the translation.  If you are using PHP, look into PDO bindParam, http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

BTW, your SQL won't work because you would need to quote (') the get variable in the SQL.

Comment: Yeah, that was just a quick type up for this post. Not my actual code. Also, the guy who has posted below confirms what I thought about md5 but contradicts what you say.. hmmm . This is hard for a beginner

Comment: I disagree with the statement that MD5 prevents SQL injection whole heatedly.   In my opinion, using bound variables is the easiest/safest/least effort way to avoid SQL injection, but of course there is a learning curve to it.  Usually it's a bad idea to put variables directly in SQL no matter what.

Comment: How does it "fake out" the MD5 function? If you call `md5()` in PHP before substituting into the SQL, the `;DROP` will be encoded into the MD5 string.

Comment: @Barmar I agree, that using MD5 in PHP before substitution is a workable solution (I answered similarly, as did you).  There is a problem if using the MD5 statement as the question describes, where the MD5 function could be executed by MySQL, which could lead to SQL injection.  As you described in your answer, using MD5 to convert all the data is a solution, but as you mentioned, would require changing all the data stored to MD5 and MD5 is one-way.  Parameter bound queries provides both a solution for SQL injection and keeping data usable.  Use MD5 where obfuscation is needed/desired.

Comment: It's not clear how he's using it in the question. His statement isn't valid PHP or MySQL, he doesn't show where he's quoting and concatenating.

Comment: @Barmar - correct, it isn't clear what the author intended, but can be interpreted both ways.  So I offered a warning of using end-user accessible variables directly in SQL and suggested a couple ways to proceed.  Still standing my my answer that MD5 will not prevent SQL injection, it's proper implementation of MD5 that does this.  We both demonstrated proper ways to do this in our answers. :)

Answer (score 1):

> I'm confused as this seems so simple, if md5 stops sql injection why isn't username and password always saved in hash form?

The reason is because simple operations like searching for a user with a particular name would be impossible.

```
SELECT * FROM users where user LIKE '%cat%'
```

Would find all users with the word cat within it.

Also simple administration would be impossible, you can't even view a roster of all users.